# how to i make unique username and retrieve data from WAMS

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I trying to do a login register page using windows azure mobile services as a database. I having problem of when I register as a user, I able to register with 2 same username. Is it possible to make username unique so i wont have duplicate username. I also wonder how do i retrieve back the data in WAMS so that i able to check for username and password to make the login part work. FYI btn1 is for login and btn2 is for register. Do help me out on what to do. Thanks.

LoginRegister.java

```
package mp.memberuse;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.TableOperationCallback;

public class LoginRegister extends Activity {

Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
EditText tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, tf7, tf8, tf9, tf10, tf11;
TextView tv1, tv2;

private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private MobileServiceTable<Members> mMembersTable;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.lt2tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    TabSpec ts1 = tabs.newTabSpec("Login");
    ts1.setIndicator("Login");
    ts1.setContent(R.id.c1);
    tabs.addTab(ts1);

    TabSpec ts2 = tabs.newTabSpec("Register");
    ts2.setIndicator("Register");
    ts2.setContent(R.id.c2);
    tabs.addTab(ts2);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    tf1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tf2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tf3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    tf4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    tf5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    tf6=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    tf7=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    tf8=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    tf9=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    tf10=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);

    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

    try {
        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL and key
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                  "**************",
                  "**************",
                  this
            );

        // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use
        mMembersTable = mClient.getTable(Members.class);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
        }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String username, password;
            username = tf1.getText().toString();
            password = tf2.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String username, password, cpassword, fullname, nric, address, phone, email;
            username = tf3.getText().toString();
            password = tf4.getText().toString();
            cpassword = tf5.getText().toString();
            fullname = tf6.getText().toString();
            nric = tf7.getText().toString();
            address = tf8.getText().toString();
            phone = tf9.getText().toString();
            email = tf10.getText().toString();

            if (mClient == null) {
                return;
            }

            Members mbs = new Members();

            mbs.setUsername(username);
            mbs.setPassword(password);
            mbs.setFullname(fullname);
            mbs.setNric(nric);
            mbs.setAddress(address);
            mbs.setPhone(phone);
            mbs.setEmail(email);

            if(!password.equals(cpassword))
            {
                tv2.setText("Password & Confirm Password does not match.");
            }
            else if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || cpassword.equals("") || fullname.equals("") || nric.equals("") || address.equals("") || phone.equals("") || email.equals(""))
            {
                tv2.setText("Do not leave any field empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                mMembersTable.insert(mbs, new TableOperationCallback<Members>() 
                {

                            public void onCompleted(Members entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) 
                            {

                                if (exception == null) 
                                {
                                    tv2.setText("Register Complete.");
                                    tf3.setText("");
                                    tf4.setText("");
                                    tf5.setText("");
                                    tf6.setText("");
                                    tf7.setText("");
                                    tf8.setText("");
                                    tf9.setText("");
                                    tf10.setText(""); 
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    tv2.setText("Fail to register!");
                                    tf3.setText("");
                                    tf4.setText("");
                                    tf5.setText("");
                                    tf6.setText("");
                                    tf7.setText("");
                                    tf8.setText("");
                                    tf9.setText("");
                                    tf10.setText("");
                                }

                            }
                });         
            }
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            tf3.setText("");
            tf4.setText("");
            tf5.setText("");
            tf6.setText("");
            tf7.setText("");
            tf8.setText("");
            tf9.setText("");
            tf10.setText("");           
        }
    });
}
}
```

Members.java

```
package mp.memberuse;

public class Members {

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
private int mId;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("username")
private String mUsername;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("password")
private String mPassword;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("fullname")
private String mFullname;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("nric")
private String mNric;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("address")
private String mAddress;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("phone")
private String mPhone;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("email")
private String mEmail;

public Members() {

}

public Members(int id, String username, String password, String fullname, String nric, String address, String phone, String email) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setUsername(username);
    this.setPassword(password);
    this.setFullname(fullname);
    this.setNric(nric);
    this.setAddress(address);
    this.setPhone(phone);
    this.setEmail(email);
}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public final void setId(int id) {
    mId = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return mUsername;
}

public final void setUsername(String username) {
    mUsername = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return mPassword;
}

public final void setPassword(String password) {
    mPassword = password;
}

public String getFullname() {
    return mFullname;
}

public final void setFullname(String fullname) {
    mFullname = fullname;
}

public String getNric() {
    return mNric;
}

public final void setNric(String nric) {
    mNric = nric;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return mAddress;
}

public final void setAddress(String address) {
    mAddress = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return mPhone;
}

public final void setPhone(String phone) {
    mPhone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return mEmail;
}

public final void setEmail(String email) {
    mEmail = email;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server script when you insert a new value into your table to check whether that name already exists in the table. For an example, check [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/validate-modify-and-augment-data-android/). Also, please don't store the plain password in your table, but use that same insert script to hash the password and store the hash.

Josh Twist has a [good blog post](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) showing how to build custom identity with Mobile Services.

Thanks, Yavor